# Adding geographical information on a registration page

Tags: api, google-maps

I'm trying to get my head around developing a delivery app for restaurants where I make a a WP site with WooCommerce and a local payment gateway. I need the app to only allow registrations from addresses a certain distance, in accordance with how far the store wants to do deliveries.

I'm pretty sure you can integrate Google Maps API into the registration forms, I'm just not quite sure how to do it.

EDIT:

As comments have noted it probably would be easier to hardcode postcodes that the shop is willing to deliver to than actual geocoding

Comment: You'll need to hook the registration post, call some API (which could be Google Maps) to geocode the address, compute the distance to the restaurant - I assume you're happy with as-the-crow-flies distance, you don't need driving distance? - and then add a validation error to the form. I'd also cache the geocode lookup somewhere. Which bit do you need help with? (I assume WooCommerce registrations use the same mechanism as normal WordPress registrations?)

Comment: It might also be easier to just hard-code a list of postcodes or zipcodes that your restaurant is willing to deliver to, and validate against that rather than actually geocoding.

Comment: Keep in mind with diistance it's not as simple as GPS location. E.g. my current location is a mile and a half from a friends house, but I didn't mention most of that distance is a river and it's 2 train journeys to get there. At least in the UK you can do this via postcode prefixes, otherwise you're going to need to use a 3rd party API mapping service. You're also going to need the location the user intends to deliver to, not their current location, otherwise people can't order things to other peoples houses, or order in advance so stuff arrives when they get home

Comment: Also, what if I want to order to a place that I don't live in? I need to register with a billing address outside the area but can't, even though the shipping address might be nextdoor to the store